# Linear Forms, Rank-Nullity

Tags: linear-algebra

Question:
Let V be a vector space and let $f1, f2, ... fn$ be linear forms on V whose kernel $f1,..,fn$ have intersection of the zero vector. Prove that V is finite dimensional and that the dimension of V is smaller than n. There is a hint given which says to find a suitable mapping from V to $K^n$ where K is the field of scalars. Any help would be appreciated.

I am unsure about this hint, will this mapping (say T) take a list of n vectors in V and map them to each f(i) (the linear forms) and then by the Rank-Nullity Theorem since the kernel of this particular linear transformation is 0, the dimension of V must be smaller than the dimension of the image of T which is n?

Comment: you are right sorry I edited that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider $$T:V\to\mathbb{K}^n$$ defined by $T(v)=\big(f_1(v),f_2(v),...,f_n(v)\big).$ Applying Rank's theorem you get 
$$\dim V=\dim\ker T+\mathrm{rank}\,T.$$ As $\mathrm{Im}\,T\subset\mathbb{K}^n$ and $\dim\mathbb{K}^n=n$ you get that $\mathrm{rank}\,T=\dim\mathrm{Im}\,T\leq n.$ Then you can see that $$v\in\ker T\iff(f_1(v),...,f_n(v))=(0,...,0)\iff f_1(v)=...=f_n(v)=0\iff v\in\cap_{i=1}^n\ker f_i$$ and as this intersection is $\{0\}$ by hypothesis you get that $\ker T=\{0\}$ and $\dim\ker T=0.$ Thus, $\dim V\leq n.$